# PHP - move an array of collection into sub array as the followings

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following array of strings (file path).I have to create tree directory andn files structure from the list of paths in the array. the purpose is to create hierarchical tree representation upto n-children based on the path as in JSON structure below

```
$paths = [
    "base/Android.txt",
    "base/Ios.txt",
    "base/Windows.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Andoid/high/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Android/high/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Android/low/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Ios/low/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Ios/medium/file.txt",
];
```

and I want to convert them into following structure of JSON or PHP Array

````
{
    "label":"root",
    "children":[
       {
          "label":"base",
          "children":[
             {
                "label":"Android.txt",
                "children":[]
            },
            {
               "label":"Ios.txt",
               "children":[]
            },
            {
               "label":"Windows.txt",
               "children":[]
            },
            {
               "label":"testDirectory",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "label":"Android",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "label":"high",
                           "children":[
                              {
                                 "label":"file.txt",
                                 "children":[]
                              },
                              {
                                 "label":"file.txt",
                                 "children":[]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "label":"low",
                           "children":[
                              {
                                 "label":"file.txt",
                                 "children":[]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"Ios",
                     "children":[
                        {
                           "label":"low",
                           "children":[
                              {
                                 "label":"file.txt",
                                 "children":[]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "label":"medium",
                           "children":[
                              {
                                 "label":"file.txt",
                                 "children":[]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}```

i tried to write but got stuck and could not able to do so, help me forks please
````

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the PHP code that you have completed so far pertaining to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
<?php

$paths = [
    "base/Android.txt",
    "base/Ios.txt",
    "base/Windows.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Andoid/high/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Android/high/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Android/low/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Ios/low/file.txt",
    "base/testDirectory/Ios/medium/file.txt",
];

$result = [];
$root = ['label' => 'root', 'children' => []];

foreach ($paths as $path) {
    $current = &$root;
    $directories = explode('/', $path);
    $file = array_pop($directories);
    foreach ($directories as $dir) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($current['children'] as &$child) {
            if ($child['label'] == $dir) {
                $current = &$child;
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            $new = ['label' => $dir, 'children' => []];
            $current['children'][] = $new;
            $current = &$new;
        }
    }
    $current['children'][] = ['label' => $file, 'children' => []];
}

$result = $root;

print_r(json_encode($result));

?>
```

Using the `explode()` function and looping through it.

PHP online: https://onlinephp.io/c/25a38